# HTLM script error with loadDeferredStyles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know HTML and CSS fairly well, but java not so much. Chrome is rendering my page almost perfectly, but I am getting the following error in the Chrome developer console. I would just remove this script, but I am trying to see if its causing a styling error with form fields where placeholder text is not showing initially, but will after field is focused and then blurred (clicked and unclicked).

Error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null at loadDeferredStyles (Quick_Quote.html:5984)"

Code Snippet:

```
<script>
    var loadDeferredStyles = function() {
        var addStylesNode = document.getElementById("deferred-styles");
        var replacement = document.createElement("div");
        replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent;      <--! Error in this line (5984) -->
        document.body.appendChild(replacement)
        addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);
    };
    var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
    if (raf) raf(function() { window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0); });
    else window.addEventListener('load', loadDeferredStyles);
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have HTML with an element with an `id="deferred-styles"`? It seems that you do not.

Comment: if you do have an id="deferred-styles", then the page isn't done loading.  which JS line is actually calling your `loadDefererredStyles`?  One of them is firing too soon.

Answer (score 0):

Put the condition If `id="deferred-styles"` element is found, then the next code is run, otherwise the code is ignored.

```
<script>
    var loadDeferredStyles = function() {
        var addStylesNode = document.getElementById("deferred-styles");
        if(addStylesNode){
            var replacement = document.createElement("div");
            replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent;
            document.body.appendChild(replacement)
            addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);
        }
    };
    var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
              webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
    if (raf) raf(function() { window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0); });
    else window.addEventListener('load', loadDeferredStyles);
</script>
```